# How to convert UTC value to NYC/eastern?

Tags: python, pandas, epoch

I have epochs in a pandas series:

```
0       1654769460000
1       1654772040000
2       1654774680000
3       1654776000000
4       1654776420000
            ...      
2050    1655423700000
2051    1655423760000
2052    1655423820000
2053    1655423880000
2054    1655423940000
Name: t, Length: 2055, dtype: int64
```

I then convert them to pandas datetimes:

```
time_stamp = pd.to_datetime(final_df['t'], unit='ms')
```

My timezone is UTC - 4 so it's the wrong time. I need the time in NYC.

I try to print the following:

```
print(time_stamp.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('America/New_York'))
```

But it returns nothing - not even an error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.dt.tz_convert`

```
df['tEST'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t'], utc=True, unit='ms').dt.tz_convert('America/New_York')
```